# Получить сумму чисел в текстовом поле

Tags: mysql, регулярные-выражения

Имеется текстовое поле в таблице, примерно такого содержания:

```
  Какой-то текст 
  ::request_points|0|request_schedule::90::/request_points|0|request_schedule::
  Какой-то текст
  ::request_points|1|request_schedule::90::/request_points|1|request_schedule::
  Какой-то текст
  .
  .
```

Как написать запрос, который считает сумму чисел заключенный между `::request_points|i|request_schedule::`. Т.е. а нашем случае 90 + 90 = 180

Использовать `REGEXP`?

```
SELECT SUM(что?) REGEXP "(::request_count_plan::).*.*(::/request_count_plan::)"
```

Всем спасибо!

Comment: regexp не поможет так как он только может проверить если значение соответсвует шаблону. Изменять значение он не умееет. Похоже без хранимой процедурки не обойтись.

Comment: @MikhailChibel наверное, я недостаточно понятно написал. Нужно посчитать сумму чисел, изменять ничего не нужно.

Comment: Я правильно понял. Я сказал что регулярным выражением скорее всего вытащить все числа не получится. Если бы у вас было только одно число в строчке тогда еще куда  ни шло. Я бы посоветовал написать процедуру по извлечения суммы чисел из строки

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Регулярные выражения в MySQL довольно не удобные, с их помощью решить задачу практически невозможно. Лучше всего создать хранимую функцию `sum_request_schedule()`, которая будет разбирать строку, извлекать из нее цифры и суммировать. Для удобства ниже мы вводим дополнительную функцию `str_count()`, которая подсчитывает количество вхождений подстроки в строку.

```
DELIMITER //
-- Вычисляет количество вхождений подстроки substr в строку content
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS str_count//
CREATE FUNCTION str_count(
  substr TEXT,
  content TEXT
)
RETURNS INT
READS SQL DATA
BEGIN
  RETURN ROUND((LENGTH(content) - LENGTH(REPLACE(content, substr, ""))) / LENGTH(substr));
END//
```

С использованием этой функции уже гораздо удобнее создать, нужную нам функцию `sum_request_schedule()`

```
-- Подсчет суммы элементов в строке
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS sum_request_schedule//
CREATE FUNCTION sum_request_schedule(
  content TEXT
)
RETURNS INT
READS SQL DATA
BEGIN

  DECLARE i INT DEFAULT 0;
  DECLARE pos INT DEFAULT 1;
  DECLARE start_num INT DEFAULT 0;
  DECLARE end_num INT DEFAULT 0;
  DECLARE result INT DEFAULT 0;

  WHILE i < str_count('request_schedule::', content) DO
    SET start_num := LOCATE('request_schedule::', content, pos);
    SET end_num := LOCATE('::', content, start_num + LENGTH('request_schedule::'));
    SET result := result + SUBSTRING(
                            content,
                            start_num + LENGTH('request_schedule::'),
                            end_num - start_num - LENGTH('request_schedule::'));
    SET pos := end_num;
    SET i := i + 1;
  END WHILE;

  RETURN result;
END//
```

После этого, вы можете использовать функцию `sum_request_schedule()`, как обычную функцию MySQL

```
SELECT sum_request_schedule("Какой-то текст 
  ::request_points|0|request_schedule::90::/request_points
  |0|request_schedule::Какой-то текст
  ::request_points|1|request_schedule::90::/request_points
  |1|request_schedule::Какой-то текст") AS result;
+--------+
| result |
+--------+
| 180    |
+--------+
```